# For complex number z = 3 - 2i, why is Im(z) -2 and not -2i?

Tags: complex-numbers, definition

The general part of the mathematical area of complex numbers is having me stumped, and I feel like as soon as I understand this, it may broaden my understanding of every consequent part of this topic (that I'm currently studying at A-Level).

For a given complex number z, where z = 3 - 2i (for example), why do we express Im(z) as -2 as opposed to -2i? And if we did express Im(z) as -2i, what sort of effect would this have on calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the definition.  It can be what we want.  And what we want when we say "Re(3-2i)" and "$Im(3-2i)$" is not the "real component" or "complex component" which would be "the real number $3$" or "$2\sqrt{-1}$".  If we *wanted* those we could have them and call them anything we want.

But we *don't* want them.  We want something else that answers *this* entirely different question:  A complex number is composed be affixing a real number component and another real number times $\sqrt{-1}$--- what are the two real numbers that we use to create the complex number?

Your question is a bit like asking why when someone ask what your last name is why we say "Ford" and not "Mr. Ford".  After all, we don't want people calling us "hey, Ford!"-- we want people calling us "hey, Mr. Ford".  Well.... fine... but that wasn't the *question*.  We didn't ask "how do we refer to you by your last name"; we asked "What *is* your last name".

If we actually go into how the complex numbers are defined it might make more sense.

Saying $z = 3 - 2\sqrt{-1}$ is a bit of a handwaving cheat; not so much because it is wrong but because it isn't really defined.  We can't wave our hands in the air and say "yesterday there was no such thing as $\sqrt{-1}$ and today there is.  Poof.  We call it $i$."

The real definition is:

A complex number is a two dimensional pair of real numbers $(a,b)$ with a multiplication operation defined as such $(a,b)\times(c,d) = (ac - bd, bc + ad)$ (and the addition operation is the more intuitive $(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+b, b+d)$.

Off hand neither number of the pair is more "real" or "imaginary" than the other.  The only difference is $a$ is the first of the pair, and $b$ is the second of the pair.  And we call the first of the pair $Re(z)$ and we call the second of the pair $Im(z)$.  And that's all they mean.

Now, the student should be shouting: Wait, *WHY* do we *call* them Real and Imaginary parts if we only mean "first" and "second" parts.

Well,  because if we take the set of all complex numbers where the second part is strictly $0$ then we get that algebraically that set is completely equivalent to the real numbers.  That is $(a,0) + (c,0) = (a + c, 0)$ and $(a,0)\times (b,0) = (ab - 0, a*0 + b*0)= (ab,0)$.  so if we identify $b \equiv (b,0)$ we, in essence have the real numbers as a subset of the complex numbers.

So the complex numbers is a set of pairs of real numbers.  The first of the pair is called the "real" part because it by itself (if the other part is $0$) acts as a real number.  We call the second of the pair the "imaginary" part because... well, the opposite of real is imaginary.

In notation we have $(a,0) \mapsto  a \in \mathbb R$ and we have $(0,b)^2 =(0, b)\times (0,b) = (0*0 - b*b,0*b + b*0) = (-b^2,0)\mapsto -b^2$ we realize we can claim $(0,b)\mapsto \sqrt {-b^2} = b\sqrt{-1}$.   We call $(0,1) \equiv \sqrt{-1} = i$ and as $i$ and $1$ can't mix (like oil and water) we can use the notation $(a,b) \mapsto a + bi$ without any inconsistencies.

This allows us to not just say that $(a,0)$ is *equivalent* to $a$ and $\{(a,0)|a \in \mathbb R \}$ is *equivalent* to $\mathbb R$.  We can say $(a,0) = a + 0*i = b$ *IS* $a$. And $\{(a,0)|a \in \mathbb R \}$ *IS* $\mathbb R$.

And although the imaginary *component* of $3-2i$ is $2i$ the imaginary *part* is the real value we put in the component; $-2$.

And we note that if we take the set of  all the complex number where the second number in the pair is

Comment: Wow, that's quite in depth. Thank you! (By the way, I'm quite like that on a lot of things. I'm just curious as to why things are the way they are)

Answer (score 2):

If $z=x+iy$ when $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ then by definition $Re(z)=x, Im(z)=y$. The reason? Because we need $y$ much more than $yi$, that's it. Using the real and imaginary part as I just defined them we can easily define norm, argument and so on.

Comment: Is there a place where I can read up on this? I've always been interested in how and why mathematicians/physicists came up with new areas in their respective fields. I'm quite stubborn that way :)

Comment: You mean read about complex numbers? I'm sure there is a lot of information in the internet. You can try to google about history of complex numbers.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

**By definition**, when we write a complax number $z$ as $a+bi$, with $a,b\in\mathbb R$, then the real part and the imaginary part of $z$ are $a$ and $b$ respectively. Then we defined the absolute value $\lvert z\rvert$ of $z$ as $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. If the imaginary part was $b$, this formula would have to become $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ in order to make sense. And the imaginary part function would not be a function from $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb R$ anymore.